# move all files created with yesterday timestamp- POWERSHELL

Tags: powershell, move

I'm trying to move all files which have been created today-1day (yesterday). I have no idea whats wrong, cause when I set $which_day as -1 i got 'no files found' but when i'll change $ as 0 all files are moved.

```powershell
###############PAR#############
$which_day = -1 
$filter = "*.*"  
$path = "E:\log_test"  
$path_destination = "E:\yesterday_log" 

$save_log = 1 
$path_log_folder = "E:\yesterday_log"  
$logname = "$path_log_folder\MOVED_FILEsLog_$(get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss").txt" 
######################################


$limit_from =  (Get-date (Get-date -Format d)).AddDays($which_day) 
$limit_to = (Get-date (Get-date -Format d)).AddDays($which_day + 1) 

$files_to_copy = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include $filter -Recurse | Where {$_.CreationTime -ge $limit_from -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit_to} 
$files_to_copy | Select Name, Directory, LastWriteTime  
Write-Host $files_to_copy.Count "files were found"  
$ID=1
$OK=0
$NOK=0
Foreach ($file_to_copy in $files_to_copy){
    $file_path = $file_to_copy.FullName
    $file_path = $file_path.Replace($path,"")
    $destination_file_path  = $path_destination + $file_path
    $destination_file_path = $destination_file_path.Replace($file_to_copy.Name, "")
    $destination_file_path = $destination_file_path.Substring(0,$destination_file_path.Length-1)
    $destination_file_path
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $destination_file_path)){New-Item $destination_file_path -Type Directory}
    Move-Item -Path $file_to_copy -Destination $destination_file_path -force

        if (Test-Path $file_to_copy) #check if moved
            {
                $NOK++
                "$ID WARNING: File $file_to_copy NOT MOVED" | Out-File -FilePath $logname -Append 
            }
        else {
                $OK++
                "$ID INFO: File $file_to_copy MOVED OK to $destination_file_path" | Out-File -FilePath $logname -Append 
            }
        $ID++
}
$Quantity = $files_to_copy.Count
If ($save_log = 1)
{
    "***************************************" | Out-File -FilePath $logname -Append #SUMMARY
    "$Quantity files were Found" | Out-File -FilePath $logname -Append #ALL FILES
    "$OK files OK MOVED" | Out-File -FilePath $logname -Append #MOVED FILES
    "$NOK files NOT MOVED" | Out-File -FilePath $logname -Append #UNMOVED FILES
}
```

**Update**

```powershell
PS E:\> . .\yesterday.ps1
0 files were found
Out-File : Could not find a part of the path 'E:\yesterday_log\MOVED_FILEsLog_2015-04-22_020130.txt'.
At E:\yesterday.ps1:46 char:49
+     "***************************************" | Out-File -FilePath $logname -App ...
+                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Out-File : Could not find a part of the path 'E:\yesterday_log\MOVED_FILEsLog_2015-04-22_020130.txt'.
At E:\yesterday.ps1:47 char:36
+     "$Quantity files were Found" | Out-File -FilePath $logname -Append #ALL FILE ...
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Out-File : Could not find a part of the path 'E:\yesterday_log\MOVED_FILEsLog_2015-04-22_020130.txt'.
At E:\yesterday.ps1:48 char:28
+     "$OK files OK MOVED" | Out-File -FilePath $logname -Append #MOVED FILES
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Out-File : Could not find a part of the path 'E:\yesterday_log\MOVED_FILEsLog_2015-04-22_020130.txt'.
At E:\yesterday.ps1:49 char:30
+     "$NOK files NOT MOVED" | Out-File -FilePath $logname -Append #UNMOVED FILES
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

PS E:\> cd .\log_test
PS E:\log_test> dir

Directory: E:\log_test
```

Comment: I am unable to replicate the issue. I ran your script (modified paths, but that's it), and it copied the one file that I created in that path yesterday. I almost want to answer just to point out things you could do better in your code though...

Comment: So what I saw in your answer before you moved it was two files, one of which has the **LastWriteTime** of today, and one for yesterday... But that is not what your script looks for, it looks at the `CreationTime` property. What is the CreationTime for those files? Run: `GCI E:\log_test\* | FT Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime` and update your question with that info.

Comment: I recommend `robocopy`.